# Is there a grammatical error in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I'm writing about something and English is not my native language; is this sentence correct?

> Words are important, but what makes someone special to you is enjoying
>   the silence

Comment: Who enjoys silence here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a correct sentence on the count of grammar. However, what it says is unclear, in fact, meaningless; two ideas are put side by side and there is no connection between them. Enjoying the silence makes someone special: what silence is it? Is it that particular person's silence? If you want to say that what you might sometimes appreciate more in people is their ability to keep silent, you might say this.

- Words are important, but what can make someone special is, even more than their words, their ability to keep silent.

---

*Addition due to comment from [**Kais Hasan**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532442/is-there-a-grammatical-error-in-this-sentence/532445#comment1300709_532445)*

- Words are important, but what can make someone special to you are the moments of silence you share with them.

Comment: I mean to enjoy the silence beside a person, for example when you only sit near someone without any words and you enjoy that, how can I write that in the same theme as the sentence in the question?